# beamer, forest, bulleted list inside

Tags: beamer, lists, nodes, forest

How can I use a bulleted list in a forest environment

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Conceptual model-functional GI disorder}
\begin{forest}
[Eary life- Genetic  environmental factors,fill=yellow!50, rounded corners
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

I want it to appear like this

### Early life

- Genetic factors
- Environmental factors

This is a single node for illustration
 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` protected `itemize` environment to get the bullet, here is a illustration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Conceptual model-functional GI disorder}
\begin{forest}
[
\parbox{12em}{
\textbf{{\large Early life}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Genetic factors
\item Environmental factors
\end{itemize}
},
fill=yellow!50, rounded corners
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `block` environment with no extra packages and maybe a little simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Conceptual model-functional GI disorder}
    \begin{block}{\textbf{\large Early life}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Genetic factors
            \item Environmental factors
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can then use a `column` or `minipage` if you want to split the frame.

Here is the output for this example:

[image: Beamer output]