# How to create list at leaf node of the forest package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, forest

Suppose I want to add the list like structure instead of branches at the leaf node. How to do that for 'e', 'f', and 'g' and for 'h' and 'i' and for 'p' and 'q'? I want output like in the given image.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{report} % V changed from 12 point
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


%%% For tikz picture
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}}
\rotatebox{90}{ 
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
/tikz/>/.tip={Stealth[]},
my label/.style={%
tikz+={\node [font=\scriptsize, anchor=south east] at (.north east) {#1};}
},
for tree={%
draw,
align=center,
minimum height=20mm,
minimum width=30mm,
anchor=center,
%font=\scshape,
l sep'=10mm,
edge={->},
s sep'=10mm,
if n children=0{
tier=terminal
}{},
}
[a,
[b, l sep'=10mm
[c
[d,dashed,thick
[e] [f]
]
[g
[h,dashed,thick, s sep'=10mm]
[i,dashed,thick]
]
]
[j
[k,dashed,thick]
[l,dashed,thick]
]
]
[m, l sep'=20mm
[n, l sep'=20mm
[o,dashed,thick]
]
]
]
\end{forest}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{caption} \label{fig:connect}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127445/? I.e. put the list environment inside a `\parbox`.

Comment: I have added an image for reference. Actually, I want output like in the given image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\forestset{
  declare boolean={my folder}{0},
  folder/.append style={ for descendants=my folder},
  folders down/.style={
    for tree={grow'=0, folder},
    tier=level me,
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  /tikz/>/.tip={Stealth[]},
  folder indent'=10mm,
  before typesetting nodes={where my folder={}{
    draw,
    align=center,
    minimum height=20mm,
    minimum width=30mm,
    anchor=center,
    %font=\scshape,
    l sep'=10mm,
    edge={->},
    s sep'=10mm,
    if n children=0{tier=level me}{},
    }}
  [a,
  [b
  [c
  [d,dashed,thick
  [e,   folders down  [f][g][h]] [f]
  ]
  [g
  [h,dashed,thick, folders down [h] [i] [] ]
  [i,dashed,thick]
  ]
  ]
  [j
  [k,dashed,thick, folders down [p] [q] ]
  [l,dashed,thick]
  ]
  ]
  [m, l sep'=20mm
  [n, l sep'=20mm
  [o,dashed,thick]
  ]
  ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{report} % V changed from 12 point
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%% For tikz picture
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\newsavebox\treeA
\begin{document}
\savebox\treeA{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0,folder}
[
 [e]
 [f]
 [g]
]
\end{forest}}

    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}}
\rotatebox{90}{ 
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
/tikz/>/.tip={Stealth[]},
my label/.style={%
tikz+={\node [font=\scriptsize, anchor=south east] at (.north east) {#1};}
},
for tree={%
draw,
align=center,
minimum height=20mm,
minimum width=30mm,
anchor=center,
%font=\scshape,
l sep'=10mm,
edge={->},
s sep'=10mm,
if n children=0{
tier=terminal
}{},
}
[a,
[b, l sep'=10mm
[c
[d,dashed,thick,alias=d
]
[g
[h,dashed,thick, s sep'=10mm]
[i,dashed,thick]
]
]
[j
[k,dashed,thick]
[l,dashed,thick]
]
]
[m, l sep'=20mm
[n, l sep'=20mm
[o,dashed,thick]
]
]
]
\node[anchor=north] at ([yshift=1em]d.south) {\usebox\treeA};
\end{forest}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{caption} \label{fig:connect}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you make it flexible so that I can simply add as a child at any leaf node without worrying about their position like 'south', 'north', etc?

Comment: @ChandanGautam All you can do is to hope that cfr sees your question one day. All I would be able to do are marginal improvements.

Comment: Thanks.  it seems it is not possible using the forest package in a simple way. SO, I have achieved the same by using some other package.